# ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '172.17.5.95' (111 "Connection refused")

Tags: mariadb, ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-18.04

Trying to connect to the server machine (Ubuntu-18.04) remotely from the client machine(Ubuntu-16.04) and facing this issue.
And not able to add SSL connection in the client machine and SSL is properly configured in server

Tried adding these lines for adding certificates in the client system

```
ssl=true
ssl-ca=/opt/ssl/ca-cert.pem
ssl-cert=/opt/ssl/client-cert.pem
ssl-key=/opt/ssl/client-key.pem
```

Here is the status of my MariaDB-client

```
MariaDB [(none)]> \s
--------------
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.40-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2

Connection id:      4
Current database:   
Current user:       root@localhost
SSL:            Not in use
Current pager:      stdout
Using outfile:      ''
Using delimiter:    ;
Server:         MariaDB
Server version:     10.1.40-MariaDB-1~xenial mariadb.org binary distribution
Protocol version:   10
Connection:     Localhost via UNIX socket
Server characterset:    latin1
Db     characterset:    latin1
Client characterset:    utf8
Conn.  characterset:    utf8
UNIX socket:        /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Uptime:         22 hours 38 min 44 sec

Threads: 1  Questions: 13  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 17  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 11  Queries per second avg: 0.000
--------------

MariaDB [(none)]> show variables like '%ssl%';
+---------------------+--------------------------+
| Variable_name       | Value                    |
+---------------------+--------------------------+
| have_openssl        | NO                       |
| have_ssl            | DISABLED                 |
| ssl_ca              |                          |
| ssl_capath          |                          |
| ssl_cert            |                          |
| ssl_cipher          |                          |
| ssl_crl             |                          |
| ssl_crlpath         |                          |
| ssl_key             |                          | 
| version_ssl_library | YaSSL 2.4.4              |
+---------------------+--------------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: 1) have_ssl = disabled means the server is not able to establish a secure connection. For more information (likely cert/key not found) check the server error log file. 2) Try to connect to the remote server via telnet: telnet 172.17.5.95:3306

Comment: @Georg Richter I was trying to find the log file using ```  show variables like 'log_error';  ``` but the path to the log file was not shown there

Comment: Checked /var/log/mysql where there are some log files generated but are encrypted

Comment: What are the results of `SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user;` The deal is that that the `host` portion likely has an entry only to localhost for root, which will not allow a remote connect. To rectify, another root entry that allows root to connect from a remote host must be provided (the user, host and password is a composite primary key). As a _temporary_ option, you can set the host to `%` to test, and if good, then add a more specific host entry. Also know that the new remote connection password does **not** need to be the same as the other, and can be a more complex password, if desired.

Comment: after setting the host to ```%``` while adding the user now facing this error while trying to connect from remote system ```ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: ASN: bad other signature confirmation```